# What is the best book/guide to help explain how to manage projects by risk?

Tags: risk-management, risk, books

Our projects are very much risk focused and I'm keen to find ways to improve how we identify and manage risks.

I've noticed that "Proactive Risk Management: Controlling Uncertainty in Product Development" by Merritt, Smith & Smith is well reviewed but this was published in 2002 and I suspect there maybe new ideas that this book won't cover.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for reference; these are out of scope on SE sites.  Reference recommendations are dynamic; they change as new references are published.  Reference requests also tend to be very specific to the original poster.

Comment: Even if this question weren't a request for a book recommendation, the question *as currently posted* is too broad. Please improve your question by asking a targeted question about a concrete risk management issue that you're currently facing.

Comment: Hey Gavin, Ashok had a suggestion that may help: *"Also, if you can add more details to your question regarding what kind of product development you are working with, many people here on PMSE may be able to help you by sharing their experiences."* Additionally, I'd suggest editing your post to explain a real problem you're trying to solve. Request for resources tend to provide little value because it's not clear how those resources solve the problem. See [ask] and [about] for guidance. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

### Risk management in product development

Here is a more recent (2010) research paper on risk management in product development. It has a link to the full PDF:

- [Product development risk management and the role of transparency
  (Abstract)](http://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/74936)

The paper has references to Risk management standards and frameworks proposed by NASA, Department of Defense and Project Management Institute (PMI) as well as several more recent studies and surveys of risk management professionals.